# flyway.locations does not work in Spring Project

Tags: flyway

**What I want**

Create an specific db/migration directory for each datasource *H2 & Postgres* as well as for each profile *local, dev, test and production are expected to be used*, in this moment I have created only a common application.yaml file for all profiles and a "dev" file.

My migrations:

1. for common: db/migration/{database}, for example "db/migration/postgres", it could be also "db/migration/h2",
2. for dev: dev/db/migration/{database}, for example "dev/db/migration/h2", it could be also "dev/db/migration/postgres"

**Why**

I'm trying to do this because I think would be great to have specific migrations for dev and others only for tests, also when others clone the project they could choose whether to use a h2 in memory database or a postgres one.

The issue is that when I start the application in the dev profile, flyway only reads the migrations of the default directory "db/migration", which in my case has no data because I even moved the ".sql" files to "db/migration/postgres", and flyway stills reads it, or at least does not throw an error,  (notice that the migrations were already applied to the database, maybe it does not throw an error even when it does not detect any .sql files to migrate, or I'm wrong?)

**PD: Another curious thing that had happened to me while working with flyway, is that I always have to call the commands "baseline()" and "migrate()" programmatically from java code, since it does not work using baselineOnMigrate=true in application.properties or application.yaml**
Each application file looks like this.

```
*application.yaml*


datasource: h2
spring:
  application:
    name: blog-service
  profiles:
    active: dev
server:
  port: 8082
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.security: TRACE
```

```
*application-dev.yaml*


datasource: postgres
spring:
  config:
    import: optional:classpath:.env[.properties]
  datasource:
    url: ${PG_URL}
    username: ${PG_USER}
    password: ${PG_PASSWORD}
flyway:
  locations: classpath:/dev/db/migration/{datasource}
  baselineOnMigrate: true
```

[resources directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ij1qo.png)

The resources directory looks like in the image and the `db/migration/postgres` path has 7 migrations inside, i.e 7 .sql files.

When the app runs with this configuration, it logs the following

```
2024-02-03T15:41:26.677Z  INFO 14504 --- [blog-service] [           main] c.d.blogservice.BlogServiceApplication   : Starting BlogServiceApplication using Java 21.0.1 with PID 14504 (C:\Users\duria\Desktop\projects\projekt\dmsosa\backend\blog-service\target\classes started by duria in C:\Users\duria\Desktop\projects\projekt\dmsosa\backend)
2024-02-03T15:41:26.680Z  INFO 14504 --- [blog-service] [           main] c.d.blogservice.BlogServiceApplication   : The following 1 profile is active: "dev"
2024-02-03T15:41:27.304Z  INFO 14504 --- [blog-service] [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-02-03T15:41:27.427Z  INFO 14504 --- [blog-service] [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 117 ms. Found 4 JPA repository interfaces.
2024-02-03T15:41:28.057Z  INFO 14504 --- [blog-service] [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8082 (http)
2024-02-03T15:41:28.073Z  INFO 14504 --- [blog-service] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-02-03T15:41:28.074Z  INFO 14504 --- [blog-service] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.18]
2024-02-03T15:41:28.154Z  INFO 14504 --- [blog-service] [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-02-03T15:41:28.155Z  INFO 14504 --- [blog-service] [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1424 ms
2024-02-03T15:41:28.274Z  INFO 14504 --- [blog-service] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-02-03T15:41:28.457Z  INFO 14504 --- [blog-service] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@4ae2e781
2024-02-03T15:41:28.458Z  INFO 14504 --- [blog-service] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2024-02-03T15:41:28.535Z  INFO 14504 --- [blog-service] [           main] o.f.c.internal.license.VersionPrinter    : Flyway Community Edition 9.22.3 by Redgate
2024-02-03T15:41:28.535Z  INFO 14504 --- [blog-service] [           main] o.f.c.internal.license.VersionPrinter    : See release notes here: https://rd.gt/416ObMi
2024-02-03T15:41:28.535Z  INFO 14504 --- [blog-service] [           main] o.f.c.internal.license.VersionPrinter    : 
2024-02-03T15:41:28.547Z  INFO 14504 --- [blog-service] [           main] org.flywaydb.core.FlywayExecutor         : Database: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dmsosa (PostgreSQL 16.0)
2024-02-03T15:41:28.551Z  WARN 14504 --- [blog-service] [           main] o.f.c.internal.database.base.Database    : Flyway upgrade recommended: PostgreSQL 16.0 is newer than this version of Flyway and support has not been tested. The latest supported version of PostgreSQL is 15.
2024-02-03T15:41:28.587Z  INFO 14504 --- [blog-service] [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbValidate     : Successfully validated 7 migrations (execution time 00:00.026s)
2024-02-03T15:41:28.616Z  INFO 14504 --- [blog-service] [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Current version of schema "public": 1.7
2024-02-03T15:41:28.623Z  INFO 14504 --- [blog-service] [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Schema "public" is up to date. No migration necessary.
```

Tried changing the `locations` property of flyway programmatically with Spring, it worked

```
@Profile("dev")
@Configuration
public class FlywayDevConfig {
    @Value("${datasource}")
    private String datasource;

    @Bean
    FlywayConfigurationCustomizer customizer() {
        return configuration -> configuration
                .locations("classpath:dev/db/migration/%s".formatted(datasource));
    }
}
```

But I would like to know why it doesn't work by simply adding it in the application-dev.yaml file, for curiousity also tried to put the same flyway.locations line of code in the `application.yaml` file but it did not readed the desired location, always the default "db/migration" one.